# Nginx symbolic link

Tags: nginx, symlink

So, I would like to create create a symbolic link from `nginx/sites-available/test.io` to `nginx/sites-enabled/test.io`.

The file `nginx/sites-available/test.io` is created, and `nginx/sites-enabled/test.io` is not.

I cd into `nginx` directory and create the link:

```
ln -s sites-available/test.io sites-enabled/test.io
```

But, I got a `Broken link` from `nginx/sites-enabled/test.io`, and its content is `sites-available/test.io` where it should be `../sites-available/test.io`

What do I do wrong here?

**EDIT**
If I first cd into nginx/sites-enabled and I execute:

```
ln -s ../sites-available/test.io .
```

Then it works.

**However**, I don't understand why. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Did you try with absolute path?

`ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.io /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.io`

Comment: I do not have nginx installed. It's only a repo, hence the relative path.

Comment: So you should update your post and add information that you want keep this symlink in repository. You can also try `cd sites-enabled; ln -s ../sites-available/test.io test.io`

Comment: @MarekSkiba: Thanks for your help ! I make it work. See my edit :)